# Displaying JSon Data Into a List

Tags: jquery, json, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using worklight and trying to get data from a database and load it into a list. I managed to get the data using a SQLAdapter but I could not load this data into a list. This is what I get from the database. How can I add this data to the user interface (preferably a list) Thanks.

```
   {
   "isSuccessful": true,
   "resultSet": [
      {
         "question": "asdasdasd",
         "vote": "0"
      },
      {
         "question": "asdasdas",
         "vote": "0"
      },
      {
         "question": "123123123",
         "vote": "0"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to first parse the data into a javascript object: `var result = JSON.parse(result);`

Then you can append list items into a list already available. This uses jQuery

```
var $list = $('ul#mylist');
for(var i in result.resultSet)
{
     var item = result.resultSet[i];
     $list.append('<li>Question: ' + item.question + 
                     ' Vote: ' + item.vote'</li>');
}
```

Comment: Theres not really more to go along with it. Just make sure you have an html element <ul id ="mylist"></ul> before running the code.